# How to select middle page of FragmentPagerAdapter?

Tags: android

I've to invoke 3rd page of view-pager using FragmentPagerAdapter so I've passed value 3 to this fragment activity which loads view-pager. But It invokes still first page of page-viewer. Any solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

just use

```
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
```

if you want to go to 3rd page, because the index starts with 0.